# Boundedness of $f^{-1}(B)$ for some bounded set $B\in X$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If $f$ is a continuous mapping from a topological space $X$ onto itself, then is there any example of $f$ such that $f^{-1}(B)$ is not bounded for a bounded set $B\in X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is the null function, then $f$ is continuous and $f^{-1}\bigl(\{0\}\bigr)=\mathbb R$, which is unbounded.